# matlab global stream: Any correlation between generated sets of numbers?

Tags: matlab, random

I'm just looking for some clarification in creating sets of random numbers in matlab and how this relates to the 'global stream.'

I know that I can set the global stream for reproducibility of my results should I run the code again:

```
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',7);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
A = rand(1,10);
```

Every time I run this, A is the same.  For example,

```
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',7);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
B = rand(1,10);
```

I should find that isequal(A,B) is true.

Now my question pertains to the following,

```
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',7);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
A = rand(1,10);
B = rand(1,10);
```

If I run this then A and B are different sets of numbers.  Can I take them to be *independent* sets, or is there some correlation between them?  If I wanted to ensure stronger independence between A and B should I create a new and different globabl stream after creating A, but before creating B?  For example,

```
sA = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',7);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(sA);
A = rand(1,10);

sB = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',3);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(sB);
B = rand(1,10);
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab generate random number from a "KNOWN" but complex function,

> All pseudorandom number generators are based on deterministic algorithms, and all will fail a sufficiently specific statistical test for randomness

when you change seed number (which you could do it with rng(your_desired_seed_number) too) it just use another part of the function which is not irrelevant to previous random number sequence(at least i think that way) , (it is a mathematical question)

but i suggest to use different generators to have maximum independent random number,

```
rng(5,'twister'); % you could  also use randstream instead of rng 
A=rand(1,10);
rng(3,'combRecursive');
B=rand(1,10);
```